# How do you compare two SQLAlchemy Column objects correctly with Python's unittest?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I wrote a unit test that is supposed to compare a Column object returned from my method. I'm creating one in the test, then getting one from my class. My test code looks like this:

```
def test_getting_correct_sa_object_from_column(self):
    table = self.database.get_table_by_name('ESEventlogMain')
    column = table.get_column_by_name('eventdata')
    sa_column = sqlalchemy.Column('eventdata', sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=False)

    self.assertEqual(sa_column, column.get_sa_object())
```

And the method of my class is returning this:

```
def get_sa_object(self):
    if self.type == 'int':
        sa_type = sqlalchemy.Integer
    elif self.type == 'varchar':
        sa_type = sqlalchemy.String(self.length)

    return sqlalchemy.Column(self.name, sa_type, primary_key=self.is_primary_key)
```

When I run the test, it fails with this output:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tames.mctigue\PycharmProjects\db_setup_wizard\tests.py", line 107, in test_getting_correct_sa_object_from_column
    self.assertEqual(sa_column, column.get_sa_object())
AssertionError: Column('eventdata', Integer(), table=None) != Column('eventdata', Integer(), table=None)
```

The AssertionError shows what looks like identical data so I'm stuck on what to look for. Is there a different comparison I should be using besides "assertEqual"?

Comment: What are really really trying to test here? That DB tables exist and they have columns with names you expect? That columns have the same datatype as expected? Anything else?

Comment: I'm not actually creating any tables yet. Right now I just want to make sure the method is returning the right type of column.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use direct column, like:

```
def test_getting_correct_sa_object_from_column(self):
    table = self.database.get_table_by_name('ESEventlogMain')
    column = table.get_column_by_name('eventdata')
    sa_column = table.eventdata # <- Change this column

    self.assertEqual(sa_column, column.get_sa_object())
```